# Kafka Leader Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a kafka cluster on three EC2 machines (server-1,server-2,server-3) and zookeeper is running on server-1. server-1 has brokers ids 11,12,13, server-2 has broker ids 21,22,23 and server-3 has broker ids 31,32,33.
While trying to send a message via kafka console producer (on server-1) to topic with name test4, I'm getting the following error:

```
WARN [KafkaApi-11] Produce request with correlation id 2 from client
console-producer on partition [test4,0] failed due to Leader not local
for partition [test4,0] on broker 11 (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

The output which I get for describe topic command is :

```
Topic: test4    Partition: 0    Leader: 21  Replicas: 21    Isr: 21
Topic: test4    Partition: 1    Leader: 22  Replicas: 22    Isr: 22
Topic: test4    Partition: 2    Leader: 23  Replicas: 23    Isr: 23
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are sending messages to broker 11 but you should send them to broker 21 because this broker is leader for topic test4, partition 0. How exactly are you producing/sending these messages? Can you share the command? Isn't it possible that you somehow specified the broker 11 explicitly?

And just out of curiosity: why do you have three Kafka brokers on a single server? (If I understood it correctly.)

Comment: bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list server-1:9092,server-1:9093,server-1:9094,server-2:9092,server-2:9093,server-2:9094,server-3:9092,server-3:9093,server-3:9094 --topic test4

Comment: Right Now I'm just testing it so specified 3 brokers. I'm planning to change it to one broker per machine in the future

Comment: Hmm, that should work I think. It means that it is some stupid mistake :-). Isn't is possible that you've started your Kafka brokers on `localhost:9092` hostname or something like that? What's your `host.name` config on brokers? Maybe Kafka returned `localhost:9092` instead of `server-2:9092` and when you resolve `localhost` on `server-1` you won't get `server-2` back, obviously.

Comment: Also look at your state-change and controller logs.